# ¿Como passar una subconsulta como valores a una consulta en LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

tengo dos `DataTables` con artículos ('id' i 'nombre') y me gustaría que mediante una consulta LINQ me retornara todos los artículos que están en ambas `DataTable`.
Algo como:

```
select * from Datatable1 where id in (select id from Datatable2);
```

¿Y no sé cómo hacerlo, me podéis echar una mano por favor?
Gracias.

Comment: Revisa [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257360/linq-select-objects-in-list-where-exists-in-a-b-c/14257379) respuesta, te puede servir ;)

Comment: es preferible que lo hagas en un join

Comment: @DavElsanto así lo he hecho, gracias.

Comment: por favor, no edites tu pregunta para poner la respuesta. Aca abajo, donde dice respuesta, es donde van las respuestas ;). Y si es tu propia respuesta, mucho mejor!!!!!! voy a volver atras tu pregunta, agrega la respuesta como corresponde...

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero lo siguiente:

```
var dataTable2Ids = _dbContext.Datatable2.Select(data => data.id);

var dataTable1 = _dbContext.Datatable1.Where(data => dataTable2Ids.Contains(data.id)).ToList();
```

El método `Contains` se convertirá en un `IN` de SQL.

Comment: Pero verifica mejor no es muy aconsejable usar un in de un select

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente lo he Hecho mediante un `join`.
Como me sugieren en los comentarios, es mejor enfocarlo como un `join` que como una subconsulta.
Dejo el código por si ayuda a alguien:

```
    var dup = (from Product1 in LArticlesWC
               join Product2 in LArticles200
               on Product1.id equals Product2.id
               select Product1.id).ToList();
```

Comment: Bien hecho solo tenías que investigar un poco. Ahora intenta con lamdas jejejeje 